# Computing Linear Layer in Tensor/Outer-Product space in PyTorch is Very Slow

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, linear-algebra, tensor

I would like to make a PyTorch model that takes the outer product of the input with itself and then does a linear regression on that. As an example, consider the input vector `[1,2,3]`, then I would like to compute `w` and `b` to optimize `[1*1, 1*2, 1*3, 2*1, 2*2, 2*3, 3*1, 3*2, 3*3] @ w + b`.

For a batch `input` with `r` rows and `c` columns, I can do this in PyTorch with

`(input.reshape(r,c,1) @ input.reshape(r,1,c)).reshape(r,c**2) @ weigts + b`

My problem is that it is extraordinarily slow. Like a factor 1000 times slower and more memory consumptious than Adding a fully connected c*c RELU layer, even though it has the same number of weights.

My question is why this happens?

Is `reshape` a very expensive operation for PyTorch? Could I reformulate it in a different way that would make things more efficient?

Another equivalent formulation I know is `torch.diag(input @ weights @ input.T) + b`, but now we are computing way more values than we need (`r*r`) just to throw them away again.

Answer (score 1):

When you have to reshape a tensor during the training loop of a model it's always best to use [view](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html?highlight=view#torch.Tensor.view) instead of reshape. There doesn't appear to be any performance overhead with a view, but it does require that the tensor data is contiguous.

If your tensors at the beginning [aren't contiguous](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html?highlight=contiguous#torch.Tensor.is_contiguous) you can recopy the tensor and make it [contiguous](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html?highlight=contiguous#torch.Tensor.contiguous).

Comment: That's good to know!, but unfortunately it's not much faster :(. I guess physical reshaping is still needed to perform the subsequent multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that PyTorch has `torch.bilinear`, which is backed up by CUDA and does exactly what I need. That's neat and very fast. It still leaves the case of higher-order tensorings. I don't see any `torch.trilinear` and so forth, but for now it's great.

Comment: I'm not convinced that an outer product is going give you better insight into the data with a model. You could "sum" or just use the product of a few elements, and get similar results. If the product helps the model perform better, then you have a problem with your input data and it needs better data engineering to pull out the features. Given the right model shape it should match the performance of a model that uses a product. The difference would just be time in training and memory. You can also make training worse by creating distracting features.

Comment: @Reactgular Using outer products like this is popular in the fine-grained image classification literature as 'bilinear pooling'. I don't know of any papers using trilinear pooling, but I would still like to test it to compare with my recent paper on sketching such constructions: https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.01821